# Limited document size in flash

Tags: flash, flash-cc

My document size is 250x400

[image]

But every element that out of this canvas - still visible

[image]

How to make object invisible when they are out of canvas?

[image]

Comment: Your question is not very clear. By default objects outside the stage area are not clipped. You will have to use something like masking to show only specific areas of a MovieClip if that is what you are using. Provide some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution #1: publish settings -> HTML wrapper -> Scale -> Exact fit

solution #2: create mask with the size of stage area for every layer